# timedatectl and systemd-timesyncd services fail to set time

Tags: time, raspberry-pi, systemtime

**TL;DR: My raspberry pi won't automatically sync date and time. `timedatectl` doesn't run/times out, and upon further investigation, `systemd-timesyncd` has failed for some reason and cannot be restarted. I also don't have any error logs because the journal system refused to start on boot.**

---

Recently when I booted up my Raspberry Pi, I noticed that the system time no longer syncs automatically. I have a WiFi internet connection. Going into system configuration and re-setting the timezone didn't help, but I was able to manually set the time and date (sort of).

It's also worth mentioning that, on boot, the `journal` service failed to start, I was also getting errors about `No session for PID xxx`, and the terminal was taking a ridiculously long time processing what `sudo reboot` meant (which, oddly enough, only happened the first time today I started the Raspberry Pi).

Based off of other posts, I found that running `timedatectl` was supposed to show the system time along with more information about auto time sync. However, I instead got:

```
Failed to query server: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

I received the same error running `timedatectl status`. At this point I have rebooted multiple times with no avail. I know that my internet connection is working because I have other devices that are able to sync their time.

After looking around some more, I figured that `systemd-timesyncd` was one of the major components/services  responsible for automatic time synchronization. I ran `systemctl status system-timesyncd` and received an interesting error message:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of systemd-timesyncd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units
    systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
              disable-with-time-daemon.conf
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2021-12-19 18:15:43 CST; 3min 23s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
    Process: 1260 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd (code=killed, signal=ABRT)       
   Main PID: 1260 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
```

(Note that this was after I manually set the time, but before, the Raspberry Pi was still stuck in October).

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload` executed without any errors, to my surprise, but still didn't resolve the previous issue.

I then ran `systemctl restart systemd-timesync.service` which gave me

```
Job for systemd-timesyncd.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status systemd-timesynced.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I took a look at `journalctl -xe` but there were no entries. As I mentioned before, this likely was because the journal refused to start at boot.

At this point I am at a loss of words. I tried rebooting, and I also tried restarting the time sync process itself. I appreciate anyone who is trying to help me with this, because it really is frustrating. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wiped the disk and reinstalled raspberry pi

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact same issue after updating several Raspberry Pis from Buster to Bullseye. I was able to resolve it by reinstalling `systemd-timesyncd` with the command `sudo apt install systemd-timesyncd -y`.